# Supporting 240x480 and 1280x800 resolutions with single DENSITY_MEDIUM graphics

Tags: android, graphics, graphics2d, android-image

Right so in my game, I have my graphics in their respective folders and I scale them based on the density setting and the actual resolution. This is to ensure the game looks the same regardless of screen size/density (I make sure to keep the same aspect ratio and just show slightly more/less of the "world" depending on the ratio).

My problem with this is the difference in screen sizes between a nexus 7 and the Sony xperia mini (the new one). The former has a res of 1280x800 and the latter 240x480, but because the nexus is a 7" tablet and the Sony xperia a small phone, they are both classed as medium density (as specified by DisplayMetrics) and therefore both take their graphics from the drawable-mdpi folder.

This means I have to have my drawable-mdpi graphics be drawn to a 1280x800 scale (to ensure I only downscale)The problem is, on the Sony small graphics scaled down from 1280x800 just look nasty.

I can't really use the extra screen size qualifier because then my scaling will fail to work. For e.g. I could use drawable-large-mdpi and drawable-small-mdpi folders but because the density flag will still be the same, my code will scale graphics taken from either folder by the same amount, and since they are different sized graphics, they need to be scaled by a different amount.

I have a couple of questions:

1) Is my idea of scaling based on the density flag fundamentally wrong? The basic idea was to put the largest graphics for that density in each respective folder and scale down from there to the resolution of the device. This was to solve 2 problems: firstly to ensure the game looks the same regardless of size and density and 2) to ensure I don't have to scale up.

2) If the way I have gone about this is not fundamentally flawed, how can I provide different graphics for different screen sizes and densities while still being able to scale each by the same amount (referring to my example above by having say 480x600 graphics in the small-mdpi folder and 1280x800 in the large-mdpi folder, and knowing I need to scale them differently despite both having the same DisplayMetrics density flag)?

Thanks

Edit: This is an Opengl 2d game, in case it makes a difference (which I believe it will).

Comment: Nexus 7 is tvdpi, you can use `tvdpi` as the drawable qualifier.

Comment: Check this: "In fact the entire Jelly Bean OS contains only a single tvdpi asset, the remainder are scaled down from hdpi assets. " from [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am aware of tvdpi, but I have read that we are advised not to create specific graphics for it and treat it as a "secondary" density. I could use it in this instance but as we are advised not to create graphics for this density specifically there must be a correct or more standard way of doing it that would not require dedicated graphics for tvdpi. (Also in the version of the android sdk I am using the nexus resolution is classed as medium, it is pre-tvdpi, but like I say I am after a "better" solution than to create new graphics for the tvdpi density)

Comment: which means u only need one set of graphics that can fit them (nexus 7 and xperia mini) all? tvdpi scaling ratio is 1.33 times of mdpi, which means the graphics you put under tvdpi qualifier will automatically scale down to fit mdpi devices. Thus you may not need to create a folder for mdpi.

Comment: That's the problem, when the graphics scale down to the xperia size the smaller ones look awful. That blog article if I'm not mistaken is giving solutions for apps rather than games (it references 9 patch images). This is an opengl game so I cannot use 9 patch images. Thanks for the response though :)